# Does Java Method Reference has special treatment to a method whose first argument is the same type of the class being referenced?

Tags: java, method-reference

I have come across a use of Java Method Reference which I don't know how it can be compiled and executed successfully.

I have the following `@FunctionalInterface`:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface NotifyFunction {
    void notify(NotifyService notifyService, String message, int target);
}
```

The `NotifyService` is an interface which has some methods:

```java
public interface NotifyService  {
    public void notifyOne(String message, int target);
    public void notifyTwo(String message, int target);
}

public class ConsoleNotifyService implements NotifyService {

    public void notifyOne(String message, int target) {
        System.out.println("[ONE] " + message + target);
    }
    
    public void notifyTwo(String message, int target) {
        System.out.println("[TWO] " + message + target);
    }
}
```

I add an `enum` for containing all the *strategies*:

```java
public enum NotifyStrategy {

    // HOW???
    ONE(NotifyService::notifyOne),
    TWO(NotifyService::notifyTwo);
    
    private final NotifyFunction notifyFunction;
    
    NotifyStrategy(NotifyFunction notifyFunction) {
        this.notifyFunction = notifyFunction;
    }
    
    public void notify(NotifyService notifyService) {
        this.notifyFunction.notify(notifyService, "TEST", new java.util.Random().nextInt());
    }
}
```

I don't understand how Java can convert from `NotifyService::notifyOne` to an instance of `NotifyFunction` when:

(1) The method signatures do not match.
(2) `NotifyService::notifyOne` is a reference to an interface.

The following `main` works correctly:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    NotifyStrategy.ONE.notify(new ConsoleNotifyService());
    NotifyStrategy.TWO.notify(new ConsoleNotifyService());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8)

> A **functional interface** is an interface that has just **one abstract method** (aside from the methods of Object), and thus represents a **single function contract**.

`NotifyFunction` defines only one abstract method thus it is a valid *functional interface*.

And every *functional interface* could be implemented either by using *lambda expression* or with a *method reference*.

> I don't understand how Java can convert from `NotifyService::notifyOne` to an instance of `NotifyFunction`

There's no such conversion. `NotifyFunction` is implemented with reference to the instance method `NotifyService`

This type of **method reference** is [classified as](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

> *reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type*

If you are perplexed by the usage of interface in the method reference, here is another example:

```
BiFunction<Collection<Integer>, Integer, Boolean> func =
                Collection::add;
```

This function expects a collection (*any collection*) and an item to add. Instance method `add()` will be invoked on an arbitrary collection passed to that function, not on the `Collection` interface.

> The method signatures do not match.

We have the following method signatures for the abstract method of the `NotifyFunction` and method `notifyOne()` defined by the `NotifyService`:

```
notify(NotifyService notifyService, String message, int target)
```

```
notifyOne(String message, int target)
```

I.e. that we can implement `NotifyFunction` with lambda expression like that:

```
(notifyService, message, target) -> notifyService.notifyOne(message, target)
```

Which boils down to a method reference `NotifyService::notifyOne`.